# ERD: Can an Associative Entity have a relationship with a Weak Entity?

Tags: database-design, erd

Entity A and Entity B are strong entities and they have their own identifiers. Their Many-to-Many relationship is resolved with Associative Entity C, which has its own Identifier. I am just wondering if Entity C can have another relationship with a Weak Entity D whose existence depended on the Associative Entity C identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. You can find this in [Fundamentals of Database Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321122267) chapter: "Entity Relationship Extended" (I have the Spanish version so I'm not really sure about the exact translation)

Best regards,